# Does Hasura generate Role-based introspection?

Tags: graphql, introspection, hasura

I want to build an admin tool based on a Hasura backend.
Different users will have different level of access based on roles.

Will I be able to do **introspection per role** and therefore know which fields (from queries) and buttons (for mutations) to show?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What exactly do you mean by "introspection per role"? Is that graphql introspection? If that's so then yes: graphql introspection depends per user role.  Users of 'admin' and 'default' roles will see different schemas. And if you activate Allowed List - then introspection will be prohibited if introspection query will not be in Allowed List.

Comment: Perfect. That's the response I was hoping for!

Comment: Good. Check an extended answer - maybe you'll see something useful for you.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clarification from OP it became possible to answer this question.

Yes. Hasura generates different schema for different roles.

How to check them?

### A. Permissions summary

Go in hasura console to `https://[hasura address]/console/data/schema/public/permissions`

You will see something similar to:

[image: permissions summary]

Note here:

- `admin` role has access to all registered objects and all fields
- other roles have access to different sets of objects and different set of fields with different row security checks.

### B. Hasura API Explorer

Go to: `https://[your hasura]/console/api-explorer`.

Set `x-hasura-role` in Request Headers:

[image: Request Headers]

Try to do queries and mutations.

You'll see that sets of  objects and fields are different for different roles.

### C. Allowed List

If you activated Allowed List (which is recommended for production)
(**and if graphql inspection query is not in your Allowed List** )

then graphql inspection will be disabled for all roles except `admin`:

[image: introspection query]

For those who are interested in enabling introspection query - check https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/blob/master/server/src-rsr/introspection.json